# Entity view mode and form mode schema

Tags: 8

`node_type_example` module provides a file that defines form display configuration for a custom node type defined in this module. The file is named [core.entity_form_display.node.basic_content_type.default.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/node_type_example!config!install!core.entity_form_display.node.basic_content_type.default.yml/8).

The example file clearly sets some field settings but is there a a schema for these config files? How to build my own config file for view mode and form mode?

Comment: See core.entity_form_mode.user.register.yml that defines the entity form mode or \Drupal\Core\Entity\Entity\EntityFormDisplay entity

Comment: `core.entity_form_mode.user.register.yml` doesn't seem to be relevant. It's virtually empty and it's not configuring any fields. `EntityFormDisplay` on the other hand is a class implementing `EntityFormDisplayInterface` which is also no relevant. I'm asking about schema for the yml config files for node form mode and node view mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, form/user mode and form/user display isn't the same thing.

But the schema for all of them is in in `core/config/schema/core.entity.schema.yml`.

That said, I'm not sure why you want to *build* that file? Especially for a node type. Create the node type and the fields, configure the form and view displays in the UI, export it, add the files to your modules, don't. You don't have to build them yourself.